# "Wovon" or "von wo"?

Tags: word-choice, question, interrogative

If I would like to ask in German *"Where is this from?"*, which of the following should I say:

> - **Wovon** ist das?
> - **Von wo** ist das?

Are both sentences correct or is one of them better?

Comment: Depends on context. Both sentences are correct, but (can) have a different meaning. And the question word "woher" wouldn't be wrong per se, either.

Comment: I would say: "Woher kommt das" oder "Wo kommt das her?"

Comment: _Wovon ist das?_ sounds like an old-fashioned variant of _Woraus ist das [gemacht]?_ ‘What is this made of?’ It could also mean ‘What is this a part of? What/where does this belong to?’ _Von wo ist das?_, on the other hand, is a colloquial variant of _Woher kommt das?_

Comment: Related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/27181/wo-kommen-sie-her-or-woher-kommen-sie-what-is-the-difference and http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/16040/woher-versus-woraus/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Wovon* and *Von wo* denote different questions.

*Wovon* means something like *What is the cause.*

Example:

> Wovon ist dir schlecht geworden? (What made you sick?)

@raznagul said that *wovon* is equivalent to *von was,* which is correct. 
So you could also say

> Von was ist dir schlecht geworden?

*Von wo* means something like *Where did something originate.*

Example:

> Von wo kommt das Geräusch? (Where does the sound come from?)

Like @Crissov said in the comments, *woher* is mostly equivalent. So you could say:

> Woher kommt das Geräusch?

Comment: @raznagul Yes, _wo-_ in interrogatives has two uses/origins: locational (_wo, woher, wohin_) and referential (_womit, wodurch, wovon …_). In the latter case, it parallels either _da-_ (_damit, dadurch, davon …_) or article / demonstrative pronoun preceded by the respective preposition (_mit dem, durch die, von diesem …_) in answers. That’s certainly confusing for DAF learners.

Answer (score 1):

Armin it totally right.

However, you can always use **"Woher?"** because it has **both meanings**: *"What is the cause?"* and *"Where does it originate?"*.

**Example:** *"Woher kommt das?"* is equal to *"Wovon kommt das?"*, but also equal to "Von wo kommt das?"

Comment: Ich finde deine Antwort fehlleitend. "Woher kommt das?" und "Wovon kommt das?" werden leicht unterschiedlich verwendet. Auf "Mir ist übel." würde man eher mit "Wovon?" als "Woher?" antworten.

Comment: @Kay Oder mit "Wie", i.e. "Wie kommt's"

Comment: I have to agree with @Kay. ``Woher`` is mostly used for locations and the usage for causes is mainly in dialects. this is supported by duden, wich doesn't list your meaning for the word. [duden.de](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/woher)